# Getting error in broadcast url while using Broadcast Upload Extension

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, broadcast

I am trying to implement a Broadcast Upload extension and I'm facing url error issue. Trying Broadcast upload through various examples and finally, when i am trying to provide broadcast url i am getting the following error.

```
let broadcastURL = URL(string:"rtmp://ingest-***/stream/streamkey")
```

> -> [ERROR] Failed to determine whether URL /broadcast (n) is managed by a file provider

What is the problem here? is there any format for this url? Any specific setting which we have to mention in **userDidFinishSetup()?**

Comment: It looks like that url is not managed by the provider.  Is `***` a valid one or you do not want to show that.

Comment: @ParthaG Yes, it is valid we checked using OBS.

Comment: If there is a sample app which exhibits the behavior you have mentioned, please do share.  It might help to debug further.

Comment: please share your code.